# Electric field due to a dipole at large distances

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dipole

It says
$$
E= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{p}{r^3}
$$
so by this this eqn, if we measure electric field at a distant point then we can never find $q$ and $d$ separately. $q$ and $d$ are charge and separation between charges of a dipole. Instead we can only find $p$.

It is from *Principles of Physics*, Resnik Ch. Electric field.

I don’t get that! Please explain!

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: I guess no one noticed but it’s 2 not 4 in eqn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the derivation of the formula, there you can see that different values of $Q$ and $d$ can give the same result.

For the field a large distance $r$ along the line of the dipole

$$E= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r^2} - \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{{(r+d)}^2}$$

If $d$ is small compared to $r$

$$E= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{Q[{(r+d)}^2-r^2]}{r^4}$$

$$E= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{2Qd}{r^3}$$

So only the product of $Q$ and $d$ could be found.  If we were to get data about the field closer to the charges, $d$ could no longer be considered small compared to $r$ and the values of $Q$ and $d$ could be separately determined.

Comment: How can the values of q and d can be found

Comment: If you knew the value of $E$ when $r$ is large, you could find the product $Qd$.  If you then had a measurement of $E$ for a smaller value of $r$ e.g. $r=1$, you can get (using the first formula in the answer ) a value for $\frac{Q}{(d+1)^2}$, then with simultaneous equations you can find $Q$ and $d$.  .

Comment: I think you will get a value for Q - Q/(1+d)^2  and then by using other eqn p=Qd we can get Q and d

Comment: Yes, that seems right, so it is possible to find $Q$ and $d$ separately if you have two measurements of $E$, and one measurement is close enough to the dipole

Answer (score 1):

> if we measure electric field at a distant point then we can never find $q$ and $d$ separately. [...] Instead we can only find $p$.

This is correct. There is nothing mysterious about this, and you get the same structure whenever a quantity is given by the product of two others. (As an example, if someone is using a wrench and you can only measure the torque it produces, then you have no way of knowing the force applied and the length of lever arm it is applied at; you can only infer their product.)

If you have two opposite charges close to each other and you're observing them from far away, electrostatics tells us (via the derivation of the result you quoted) that the asymptotic field does not contain enough information to recover *any* internal details about the arrangement of charges, beyond their total dipole moment. (And indeed, it could be more than two charges, and you wouldn't be able to tell their number, charge distribution, or internal geometry.) The only way you can access this information is by getting close enough to the system that you can measure deviations from the asymptotic dipole field.

Comment: So you are saying we can measure E , put this in eqn and can get p. But not q and d separately. Right. 
But how do you measure Electric field. Is it by some instrument.

Comment: This is discussed at depth in any textbook on electrostatics or electromagnetism.

Comment: When we talk about dipoles then do we know their charges. Only then we can find Force and then Electric field. That is how we can measure E (I guess this is the method you are talking about given in textbooks)But I am asking if we were not knowing the charges or the distance between them and somehow we could measure it by some instrument. Put that in above eqn and find p.

Comment: We cannot find E by the convention because we don’t know q and d. Perhaps thats  what we have to find . So how do we measure E.

Comment: @cOnnectOrTR12 The electric field is defined as the force experienced by a small test particle, divided by the charge of that test particle, and it can be measured that way. (There are also multiple other instruments that can measure the field.) This is explained in the early sections of *every* textbook on electromagnetism; if you have to ask, it means that you did not read in sufficient detail and need to re-read with care. I'm uninterested in further back-and-forth here.